# Automating repetitive keyboards actions

Tags: python, windows, macros, scanning

I'm currently scanning a lots of documents using an old machine. I'm using Microsoft Paint dummy software to do it. The process is quite tedious as it requires me doing the following actions, once the document is ready to be scanned:

1. `[Alt]` -> `[F] -> [S]`
2. `[Tab]` -> `[down arrow]`
3. wait for the document to be scanned
4. `[Ctrl] + [S]`
5. Enter a name, which is just `n + 1.png`.
6. **Do it all over again...**

I thought that if I started by step 4., I could find a way to automate the process with a keyboard shortcut or even using voice (I saw there were tools to run macros based on predefined verbal commands).

If there are most likely tools to run keyboard shortcuts, I'm wondering if you would be aware of tools/pieces of code which would allow me to have the name of the file defaulted to n+1 so that I don't have to enter the file name myself.

In a nutshell: would you know a tool, a way to implement it? I can code in python and VBA, should it be usefull.

Thank you very much!

Sophie

Comment: `PyAutoGUI` programmatically can control the mouse and keyboard for you. [Here's the documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: @caseWestern It seems nice. I will have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

use this library and it has a proper documentation.
[Keybord](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/)

Comment: Sorry, I did not have time to look at it beforehand. It looks great. My only problem is that I couldn't find how to apply the keyboard actions to a software different than the python notebook the snippet is running on. Would you know how to tell the code to do the actions on Paint for instance, rather than on the notebook? Unfortunately I could not find other example than the one at your address. Thanks.